# SharePoint List - vLookup type functionality

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I currently maintain a excel spreadsheet that contains a list of upcoming classes. In addition to the standard columns, I also have some columns containing vLookups. These are used to populate additional information. For example, when someone sets the class country as "Australia", the vLookup sets the region to "Asia Pacific".

Worksheet 1:

- A: Class Name (Text)
- B: Class Location Country (Text)
- C: Class Region (vLookup to worksheet 2)

Worksheet 2:

- A: Country
- B: Region

I would like to move this excel file to a SharePoint list but cant figure out how to implement the same "vLookup" type function. If the class location is set to "Australia" it needs to lookup the region from another list.

Really appreciate any tips.

Thanks,

Ash

Ps. I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint has a lookup column type that can either reference information from another list or from Content Types.

[Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-HA101729901.aspx)